# How Generator expressions work internally in python?

Tags: python, expression, generator

I have tried this following code:

```
result = (x for x in range(3))


for y in result:
    print(y)
```

I am getting the following Output:

```
0
1
2
```

But when I am using this code :

```
result = (print(x) for x in range(3))


for y in result:
    print(y)
```

I am getting the following output:

```
0
None
1
None
2
None
```

Can anyone explain, Why this **None** is coming in output in second code?

Comment: `None` is the return value from the calls to `print` made inside the generator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `print(x)` prints the value of x (which is the digits that get printed) and also returns `None` (which is the `None`s that get printed)

Answer (score 5):

`print` doesn't return a value, so you are seeing `None`, which is the return for `print`, and the output from `print`. This is a classic case of using comprehension syntax for side effects, which is not using the generator/comprehension syntax to contain an actual result. You can check this by running:

```py
print(print('x'))
x
None
```